# Is it safe to change strong name key for new version of signed and published library?

Tags: c#, .net, gac, strongname, strong-named-key

While developing new libraries for product I generated keys (via Visual Studio) and signed libraries each with it own key with passwords. I've never encountered signing before and did this in hurry.

We have now decided to use a common key for all the libraries. However, these libraries have already been released, having been signed with the initial set of keys.

Is it safe now to re-sign them with another key and publish? Will it cause any problem with publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will be different assemblies, so you would have to recompile all applications and assemblies using them. But other than that, no, it won't be a problem.